# Printing (writing) Sikuli key constants

Tags: python, unicode, constants, jython, sikuli

My Sikuli script logs all operations using Python module *logging*. Problems occur when I try to write into a log a key constant that was typed. As an example I used *print* function because it requires a string too:

```
print((Key.ALT).encode('utf-8'))#exception not thrown but nothing readable is printed
print(Key.ALT)                  #UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ue022' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Of course I could compare a variable with all possible key contants:

```
myKey = Key.ALT
if(myKey==Key.CTRL):
    print('ctrl pressed')
elif(myKey==Key.ALT):
    print('alt pressed')
#etc…
```

but this is not most efficient way I guess. I could also do some other workarounds like this:

```
print(“Key.ALT pressed”)
keyDown(Key.ALT)
```

but I want to find a way to convert *Key.CONSTANT* into a printable (writable) format so that my "typing"
 function takes only 1 argument (only key constant to be used for typing and for logging). Is it possible?

Comment: that sign is simply not printable in utf-8 http://www.charbase.com/e022-unicode-invalid-character that's why you don't see anything in the logs. Have you tried a different Key and checkd what you get ?

Comment: Yes, I know it is not printable. That's why I asked this question. Is there a way to convert Sikuli Key.CONSTANT into printable format for example "Key.ALT" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if/else solution is perfectly fine.  If you wanted, you could use a dictionary instead:

```
keyStrings = { Key.CTRL  : "control-key",
               Key.ALT   : "alt-key",
               Key.SHIFT : "shift-key" }

print(keyStrings[myKey])
```

Comment: You're right, I guess there is no better solution then comparing values.

Comment: I wish I could get a list of constants from Key class but I don't think it is possible. dir(Key) returnes list of strings so it can't be used for comparison.

Comment: I think this contains all the constants. Maybe not very helpful for your purposes, though.  https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli/blob/develop/sikuli-script/src/main/java/org/sikuli/script/Key.java

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found satisfactory solution by using builtin python functions *dir* and *getattr* . There is no need to define all values one by one:

```
import re
#defining dictionary containing all possible Key values: 
keyDict = {}
for k in dir(Key):
    if(re.search("^__",k)):
        break
    else:
        keyDict[k] = getattr(Key,k)

#example of dictionary usage for comparison:
myKey = Key.TAB
for d in keyDict.keys():
    if(keyDict[d]==myKey):
        print("Found key = " + d)
```